# Convertir un switch a linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

¿Hay alguna forma de convertir este **SWITCH** a **LINQ**?

```
switch (row["grupo"])
{
    case "Genera ICAs":
        enuMetodo = TipoMovimientosStock.GeneraIca;
        break;
    case "Genera Remito de Compras":
        enuMetodo = TipoMovimientosStock.GeneraRemitoCompra;
        break;
    case "Genera ECAs":
        enuMetodo = TipoMovimientosStock.GeneraEca;
        break;
    case "Enciende Usa Partida":
        enuMetodo = TipoMovimientosStock.EnciendeUsaPartida;
        break;
}
```

Comment: tal vez.. si contruyeras una lista de tu switch e hicieras la busqueda de lo que viene en row. vas a tener que decir que es row, si esos son todos los case, e igual es un sinsentido te lo digo desde ya.

Comment: Exactamente tiene que explicar que es lo que almacena row, para que pueda hacer una búsqueda con linq dentro de ella. De todas formas el switch que quieres hacer dentro de un linq seria como un if anidado usando el operador ternario ?:, te recomiendo mejor que uses Dictionary<string, TipoMovimientosStock> para encontrar el enum basado en el string. Te quitas almenos 9 líneas de código si omites las { son 7, practicamente la mitad. Si te interesa te puedo poner un ejemplo.Por cierto puedes usarlo en linq tambien

Comment: ¿Qué tipo es `enuMetodo`? ¿Cuál sería la necesidad de evaluarlo con Linq en lugar del `switch`?

Comment: `TipoMovimientosStock` es una `enum`?

Comment: Disculpen por no especificar.  **TipoMovimientosStock** es de tipo **enum**.  El **row** viene de una lista de **DataRow**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pesar de que no has aclarado si `TipoMovimientosStock` es una `enum`,como todo apunta a que si me voy a arriesgar a añadir una respuesta,ya que me parece interesante mostrar el método que voy a explicar a continuación.

Hay una posibilidad de hacer lo que quieres utilizando el atributo `Description` que puede aplicarse a los `enum`. Lo primero debes añadir:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

para poder usar el mencionado atributo `Description`.

Posteriormente, modifica tu `enum` de la siguiente manera:

```
public enum TipoMovimientosStock
{
    [Description("Genera ICAs")]
    GeneraIca,
    [Description("Genera Remito de Compras")]
    GeneraRemitoCompra,
    [Description("Genera ECAs")]
    GeneraEca,
    [Description("Enciende Usa Partida")]
    EnciendeUsaPartida
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, podemos usar LINQ para comparar el valor que tienes en `row["grupo"]` con la descripción que hemos añadido a la enumeración:

```
enuMetodo = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TipoMovimientosStock)).Cast<TipoMovimientosStock>()
       .FirstOrDefault
       (value =>
   (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()), typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute)
      .Description == row["grupo"]);
```

Debes tener en cuenta que para que este método funcione, todas las opciones de tu enumeración deben tener un atributo `[Description("")]` (aunque sea vacio) ya que si no el código fallará con un `NullReferenceException`.

De todas maneras dado el reducido número de opciones, por rendimiento y posiblemente por claridad de código, yo me quedaría con el `switch`. Este método podría merecer la pena si el numero de opciones en tu `enum` fuera mas elevado.

Comment: El **Switch** en realidad tiene como **25 casos**. Lo recudí para que sea más fácil de entender. Ya voy a probar tu solución y te aviso.